# Detect if mysql or mysqli is being called for connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is there a way to check which type of mysql connection is being called `mysql` or `mysqli`. what I want to do is have a If statement to call mysql or mysqli connection until I can change out all my coding.

this is my current connection file. would just duplicating what's below but with mysqli accomplish what i'm trying to do?

```
$dbc = mysql_connect ($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db ($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

    $g_link = false;

    function GetDbConn()
    {
        global $g_link;
        if( $g_link )
            return $g_link;
        $g_link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password') or die('Could not connect to server.' );
        mysql_select_db('social_db', $g_link) or die('Could not select database.');
        return $g_link;
    }

    function CleanUpDB()
    {
        global $g_link;
        if( $g_link != false )
            mysql_close($g_link);
        $g_link = false;
    }
```

Comment: I think the best way is to make sure you know how your code connects to the database. You don't want to mix and mash them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_resource_type`  function:

```
if(is_resource($g_link)  &&  get_resource_type($g_link)=='mysql link'){
   echo 'MYSQL';
}else{
    if(is_object($g_link)  && get_class($g_link)=='mysqli'){
        echo 'MYSQLI';
    }

}
```

Also, it's better to save connection type when you want to create connection and then use it.

Answer (score -1):

There is absolutely no point in checking which type of mysql connection is being called mysql or mysqli.
While changing "all your coding", you have to make use of some sort of **db access library**, which will be obviously using a new driver as it's underlying level. And as this library obviously have to be written using new api, no verifications ever needed.

While just rewriting old api calls to the new api calls will make no sense.